# Data not inserted in BIGINT datatype of mySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert following data in BIGINT datatype but it is given an error "**Out of range value for column 'bts' at row 1**"

Data: **110121014322232000011**

Please help how to insert this data to mySQL table. I am using mySQL 5.7.21

Comment: The integer literal you pasted above should be within the allowable limit for a `BIGINT` column.  Maybe you have some other data which is causing this error?

Comment: Signed or unsigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely ...

```
max allowed signed (2)63 =     9223372036854776000
Max allowed unsigned (2)64 =  18446744073709552000
Your number                  110121014322232000011
```

Form [MySQL manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)